# Touchpad periodically doesnt register input (Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy)

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, dell-vostro

I've had this issue for about a year. The touchpad periodically stops registering input, that being just touching to move the cursor, or using the physical buttons to click on something, or any of the supported gestures.
To put it as clearly as possible, **the touchpad periodically stops working completely for about a second**, sometimes more sometimes less.

What I've tried:

- A simple restart - it used to fix the issue for a couple of minutes, maybe, but this should not be trusted as it relies on me remembering correctly.
- A clean reinstall of the OS - did nothing
- I've been using a USB mouse for awhile - the USB mouse works fine, as expected
- I've updated to the latest Ubuntu 23.10 - didnt fix the issue, ive since gone back to 22.04 (also done with a clean wipe)
- I wanted to try disabling gestures for the touchpad in the BIOS, as was recommended in another simliar post, but i do not have any options relating to the touchpad in the BIOS.

It is worth noting that in the past month I've been using a usb keyboard, for no particular reason (the laptop keyboard works just fine), and the USB keyboard in question likes to cut out periodically also. The keyboard in question is the Raspberry Pi Keyboard. I've tried using a different USB port on the laptop to connect the Raspberry keyboard and that seems to limit the issue.

System Information:

- Dell Vostro 15 3515
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 6.2.0-39-generic
- DE: GNOME 41.7
- WM: Mutter (I'm not sure what this is, i got the info from screen fetch)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also almost daily run the commands 'apt update' and 'apt full-upgrade', so the system to my knowledge should be up-to-date.